# Kill activity in thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

How can I kill Android `activity` from asynchronous thread?
In my android application, I start another activity using `startActivity`. Is there anyway for me to kill that `activity` I started after several minutes?

Or is there any way beside using thread?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: For example, i make an alarm application, if the user didn't respon the alarm alert fro 15 minutes it will stop for 5 minutes and then ring again after 10 minutes.

Comment: You should use a `Service` for those kind of things, not an `Activity`

Comment: so do you mean from my activity i call service?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Yes, i have solve it.. just using runnable thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to run DT activity in a background process even though you won't have control over your application.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below link will help you to understand how to solve your task :
[BroadcastReceiver](http://www.chinaup.org/docs/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: i still don't get it.. Can you explain it more detail?

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"Status Code:404 Not Found"*.